# Server stored fonts vs Google fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts

What is better in speed and reliability, to store the font in my project (say in **Styles** folder) or to link to a font from Google?

ie

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url(gothic.ttf);
}
body {
    font-family: myfont;
}
```

or

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:bold,bolditalic|Inconsolata:italic|Droid+Sans">

body { 
  font-family: 'Tangerine', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans', serif; 
}
```

Comment: Google fonts are served from a CDN, so unless you're running a SSD server. I would suggest using them straight from google.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Advantages to storing them on your own server:

- You can use any font you have.
- You are not reliant on any other site. If google fonts was temporarily down, your site would be unaffected.
- Sometimes, google fonts will be unable to load if on an intranet. Self hosted ones can be loaded if the site is being loaded.

## Advantages to Google Fonts

- Google's fonts are compressed, so load quicker, as said in another answer.
- (Perhaps the most important factor here) Google fonts are cached. This means that there is a relatively high chance that it has already been cached on your visitors computer, as there is a high chance that that same font has been used on another website, therefore it reduces page load time.
- Google is a massive website and google fonts are massively used, so the chance of it going down are pretty low, compared to most other similar services.
- Google webfonts serve different fonts depending on which device is being used to access it. This means that you will have fewer compatibility issues, and you will need to store less fonts on you server (If you stored it on your own server, you would need to have many formats of the same font).

  ---

  On the whole, I generally prefer to use Google fonts where I can, but of course there's nothing wrong with using fonts stored on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to consider: Google Fonts may be blocked in China. If that's one of your target markets, choose accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally found that fonts stored on the same server as your files the quickest. With externally hosted files you are relying on a third parties server being as responsive as your own. There will of course be a small increase in the bandwidth use on your server (not really a problem unless you're close to your hoster's bandwidth limits).

Answer (score 0):

Google Fonts are much more lightweight than Typekit and self-hosted fonts. Google has compressed each font for speedier download, allowing each web page to download in a split second on any platform, without affecting the font quality.

Read more here:

http://webindustries.co.nz/articles/advantages-using-google-fonts-web-design